# Batch script to get all printers on computer from all users

Tags: windows, batch-file, printing, registry

I am trying to get a list of all printers (networked and local) installed to a computer from all users from a batch script.

I know how to get local printers using a batch script like so:

```
@ECHO OFF
CLS
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
REM The textfile to store the printers
SET textFile="C:\printers.txt"
REM Clear the text file and start new
COPY /Y NUL !textFile! >nul 2>&1
ECHO ==============================================================
ECHO Processing locally installed printers
ECHO ==============================================================
ECHO.
ECHO Local Printers:>>!textFile!
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%a in ('WMIC PRINTER GET NAME') do (
    SET printer=%%a
    IF NOT "!printer:~0,4!" == "Name" (
        ECHO.!printer! >> !textFile!
    )
)
ENDLOCAL
```

The problem with this script is that it will only show the printers for the user who is currently logged in. I want to process all the users on the computer. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows stores networked printers under the key `HKEY_USERS\{SID}\Printers\Connections\`. This is a good start as we can process these for all the users who are logged in. However, when a user logs out, the active user's hive gets closed and saved to `NTUSER.DAT` under their respective user's directory. `i.e. C:\Users\someuser\NTUSER.DAT`

So, with logged out users we need to load their `NTUSER.DAT` file into the registry, read the printers, and then disconnect their `NTUSER.DAT` file.

Finally, since we can easily grab local printers. The final script should look like so:

```
@ECHO OFF
CLS
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
REM The textfile to store the printers
SET textFile="C:\printers.txt"
REM Clear the text file and start new
COPY /Y NUL !textFile! >nul 2>&1

REM =================================================================================================================
REM Get all networked printers for every user who is currently logged in
REM =================================================================================================================
ECHO ==============================================================
ECHO Processing users who are currently logged in!
ECHO ==============================================================
ECHO.
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList"') DO (
    SET line=%%G
    FOR /F "tokens=3" %%X IN ('REG QUERY "HKLM\!line:~19!" /v "profileImagePath" 2^>nul') DO (
        SET userPath=%%X
        SET userPath=!userPath:*C:\Users\=!

        SET isUser=true

        REM Specify users to filter out
        IF "!userPath!" == "Administrator" SET isUser=false
        IF "!userPath!" == "defaultuser0" SET isUser=false
        IF "!userPath!" == "Public" SET isUser=false
        IF "!isUser!" == "true" (
            IF EXIST "C:\users\!userPath!\" (
                REM Make sure the key actually exists
                REG QUERY "HKU\!line:~76!" >nul 2>&1
                IF !ERRORLEVEL! EQU 0 (
                    ECHO Processing printers for !userPath!
                    ECHO !userPath!: >> !textFile!
                    REM Get all network printers
                    FOR /F "tokens=*" %%F IN ('REG QUERY "HKU\!line:~76!\Printers\Connections" 2^>nul') DO (

                        REM Format the output to only contain the printer name. Then print it to the text file.
                        SET newLine=%%F
                        SET output=!newLine:*Connections\=!
                        ECHO !output:,=\! >> !textFile!
                    )
                    ECHO.>>!textFile!
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
ECHO Logged in users are now processed.
ECHO.
REM =================================================================================================================
REM Get all networked printers for users who are logged off
REM =================================================================================================================
ECHO ==============================================================
ECHO Processing users who are logged off.
ECHO ==============================================================
ECHO.
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%D IN ('DIR C:\Users\ /B') DO (
    SET line=%%D
    SET isUser=true

    REM Specify users to filter out
    IF "!line!" == "Administrator" SET isUser=false
    IF "!line!" == "defaultuser0" SET isUser=false
    IF "!line!" == "Public" SET isUser=false
    IF "!isUser!" == "true" (
        XCOPY "C:\Users\!line!\NTUSER.DAT" "C:\Users\!line!\NTUSER_TEMP.DAT*" /H /Q >nul 2>&1
        IF !ERRORLEVEL! EQU 0 (
            REG LOAD "HKU\TempHive" "C:\Users\!line!\NTUSER_TEMP.DAT" >nul 2>&1

            REM Make sure the key actually exists
            REG QUERY "HKU\TempHive\Printers\Connections" >nul 2>&1
            IF !ERRORLEVEL! EQU 0 (

                REM Get all network printers
                ECHO Processing printers for !userPath!
                ECHO !line!: >> !textFile!
                FOR /F "tokens=*" %%F IN ('REG QUERY "HKU\TempHive\Printers\Connections" 2^>nul') DO (

                    REM Format the output to only contain the printer name. Then print it to the text file.
                    SET newLine=%%F
                    SET output=!newLine:*Connections\=!
                    ECHO - !output:,=\! >> !textFile!
                )
                ECHO.>>!textFile!
            )

            REG UNLOAD "HKU\TempHive" >nul 2>&1
            DEL /Q /A:H "C:\Users\!line!\NTUSER_TEMP.DAT"
        )
    )
)

REM =================================================================================================================
REM Get the locally installed printers
REM =================================================================================================================
ECHO ==============================================================
ECHO Processing locally installed printers
ECHO ==============================================================
ECHO.
ECHO Local Printers:>>!textFile!
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%a in ('WMIC PRINTER GET NAME') do (
    SET printer=%%a
    IF NOT "!printer:~0,2!" == "\\" (
        IF NOT "!printer:~0,4!" == "Name" (
            ECHO.!printer! >> !textFile!
        )
    )
)
ENDLOCAL
```

**NOTE:** Make sure to run this script as an administrator so it can load the `NTUSER.DAT` file into the registry

---

Additional Note: I answered my own question after I did hours of research into this and not finding an answer online. I decided to create this script and reword my original question so that if anyone else who comes across this might find some use out of it.